# NullReferenceException on SaveChangesAsync() in EF Core with SQL database in Azure

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

I searched the problem and unlike the popular answer, I don't have a view with same name of a class.
This is where the exception is thrown:

```
public async Task<Patient> AddPatientAsync(Patient newPatient)
{
    await _context.AddAsync(newPatient);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); // exception

    return newPatient;
}
```

The `AddAsync` method works and the data is stored in Azure database. But the `SaveChangesAsync` method throws the error.

The `Patient` model is this :

```
public class Patient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public string ProtectedPin { get; set; }
    public IList<DoctorAppoint> DoctorAppoints { get; set; }
    public IList<NurseAppoint> NurseAppoints { get; set; }
    public IList<LabTest> LabTests { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the `newPatient` object in watch window:

[image]

Here is the stack trace:

```
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityReferenceMap.Remove(Object entity, IEntityType entityType, EntityState oldState)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityReferenceMap.Update(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState state, Nullable`1 oldState)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StateChanging(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState newState)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState entityState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties, Nullable`1 forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.AcceptChanges()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.AcceptAllChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 changedEntries)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<SaveChangesAsync>d__101.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsync>d__7`2.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.<SaveChangesAsync>d__54.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at EchoBot.DBModels.Repositories.PatientRepository.<AddPatientAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
```

I tried removing and readding migration, update-database etc.

Comment: Does your database tables related ? if it is can you try to comment out foreign key tables and try to add again ? also does it works with sync one ?

Comment: yes the databases are relational. Where do I comment out the foreign key tables?

Comment: In the patient entity can you comment out the related entities like Gender DoctorAppoint and rest

Comment: _"I don't have a view with same name of a class"_ - you probably misunderstood the canonical Q&A about this error. What this looks like though, is an internal error in Entity Framework - are you accessing `_context` or `newPatient` from multiple threads?

Comment: @CodeCaster can't be since addAsync works and they are both in same code scope, its the only thread that using context atm. Also context being used by another thread throws different exception, not the NullReferenceException

Comment: @Halil _"can't be"_ - yes, it definitely can, not all exceptions that can arise in using a DbContext from multiple threads are documented, simply because it's not supported. This definitely looks like a threading issue, either another thread is adding Patients (or related entities), or the `newPatient` entity is modified by another thread while the change tracker is looking at the entity. That `AddAsync()` doesn't throw, doesn't mean this isn't threading-related.

Comment: @CodeCaster okay, i never faced something like that before tho, if context used by another thread, it exactly says that context is used by another but if you faced so. i think change tracker also tries to add related ones which is null so exception comes out from there

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks a lot. Looks like the I forgot to add an await calling the `AddPatientAsync` method. Maybe that's why it was multithreaded or something.. I added the await and now it works! Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Entity Framework throws random, unintelligible exceptions from deep within its internal classes, it's usually a threading issue. A DbContext is not thread-safe. You can't add entities from multiple threads.

From comments:

> Looks like the I forgot to add an await calling the AddPatientAsync method. Maybe that's why it was multithreaded

If you don't await the call to your `AddPatientAsync()` and call it in a loop, multiple threads are accessing the same `_context`. You can't do that; await the call.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really missed 'await'